# How to send form-data with RestClient, if data received from a hash?

Tags: ruby, form-data, rest-client, ruby-hash

I have an API endpoint that requires data to be sent to it as form-data. I am using RestClient for sending the data. The problem is that I do not manage to give the data for the request in a way, that the endpoint would be able to read it. This is what I have tried:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
    method: :post,
    url: url,
    payload: {
      multipart: true,
      data: {
         "user": "test",
         "phase": "test",
         "job_id": "test"
      }
    },
    headers: { Authorization: 'Basic ' + Base64.encode64(auth_details), content_type: "multipart/form-data"}
  )
```

Any advices how I could add the hash-data for the request in a way that the endpoint could read it as a form?

EDIT1:

The endpoint does receive the request. The endpoint is written with Flask and it tries to read the form parameters using flask.request in the following way:

```
request.form.get("user")
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem with what you have tried?

Comment: When the endpoint tries to read the values user, phase and job_id from the form, it receives null for each of them.

Comment: So the request actually reaches the end point? You need to post the params that the endpoint actually receives, this is most likely going to be related to structure of the hash differences with what is expected by the end point

Comment: Also do you need a multipart true option as you are not actually sending any resources?

Comment: Yes the request does reach the endpoint. I'll try removing the multipart option and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Can you post the parameters that are actually received by the end point please

Comment: Thanks for the help, managed to solve it!

Comment: Nice one, you should post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the request working by changing the reuquest to be the following:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
   method: :post,
   url: url,
   payload: {
      "user": "test",
      "phase": "test",
      "job_id": "test"
   },
   headers: { Authorization: 'Basic ' + Base64.encode64(auth_details), 
   content_type: "multipart/form-data"}
)
```